# Why do neither "done" or "fail" jQuery AJAX callbacks execute on an HTTP 500?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a little jQuery here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $this.fileUploadUrl,
    data: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(file.name),
    type: 'POST',
    done: function () {
        file.status = plupload.DONE;
        $this.updateFileStatus(file);
    },
    fail: function () {
        file.status = plupload.FAILED;
        $this.updateFileStatus(file);
    }
});
```

If the server returns a HTTP 500 response, the `fail` callback does NOT run, and neither does `done`. I even tried adding `always`, which didn't work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are `done` and `fail`? [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) does not list them.

<sup>(They *are* member functions of the `jqXHR` object, but that's not the same as them being options in a call to `$.ajax()`.)</sup>

Perhaps you're looking for `success` and `error`, respectively:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $this.fileUploadUrl,
    data: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(file.name),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        file.status = plupload.DONE;
        $this.updateFileStatus(file);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        file.status = plupload.FAILED;
        $this.updateFileStatus(file);
    }
});
```

Or, to keep your original terminology, the following (which is not quite equivalent but close-ish):

```
$.ajax({
    url: $this.fileUploadUrl,
    data: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(file.name),
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function() {
    file.status = plupload.DONE;
    $this.updateFileStatus(file);
}).fail(function() {
    file.status = plupload.FAILED;
    $this.updateFileStatus(file);
});
```

Comment: Ah, I read the documentation wrong. I saw "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."... do they intend to deprecate success and fail in the `ajax` method as well, and encourage us to use the jqXHR approach?

Comment: @JakePetroules Why would they? Such is the brilliance of a [semi-]stable API and encapsulation :) The `ajax` function just takes in an object to be able to get "named parameters".

Answer (score 2):

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: $this.fileUploadUrl,
  type: "POST",
  data: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(file.name)
});

request.done(function() {
  file.status = plupload.DONE;
  $this.updateFileStatus(file);
});

request.fail(function() {
  file.status = plupload.FAILED;
  $this.updateFileStatus(file);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this introduce a race condition?